# How to find special character from the string

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I need to find the special character index in string and it as to be stored in an array variable. 
The below code showing only the first special character  index but i need to know all index of all the special character in the string . 
Tell me how to do

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset start_var = ArrayNew(1)>

     <cfset g_invalidUsername_Char= "!@##$%^&*()_+=<>?/\,`~}{[];:.|\""0123456789">
    <cfset Firstname="ab!cd!efgh">

    <cfif FindOneOf(g_invalidUsername_Char,(trim(FirstName))) NEQ 0>    
        <cfset QAQC = 0>            
        <cfset AR=" Firstname can only have ' and - .<br>">
        <cfset ARClass ="ARBad">


        <cfset start_var= findoneof(g_invalidUsername_Char,FirstName)>
        #start_var#
        #RemoveChars(FirstName, start_var, 1)#

        </cfif> 
</cfoutput>
```

I tried Rereplace function too

```
<cfoutput>
    <cfset start_var = ArrayNew(1)>
     <cfset g_invalidUsername_Char= "! @ ## $ % & * ( ) _ + = <> ? / , ` ~ } { [ ] ; : . |  "" 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \ ">
    <cfset FirstName="ab!cd""efgh">
    <cfset var_num=0>
    <cfif FindOneOf(g_invalidUsername_Char,(trim(FirstName))) NEQ 0>    
        <cfset QAQC = 0>            
        <cfset AR=" Firstname can only have ' and - .<br>">
        <cfset ARClass ="ARBad">
        <cfloop list="#g_invalidUsername_Char#" index="x" delimiters=" ">
            #x#<br>
            <cfset FirstName = ReReplace(FirstName,"[#x#]", "", "ALL")>
            #FirstName#
        </cfloop>
    </cfif> 
</cfoutput>
```

but in rereplace function these  "\^"  two special character is not accepting

Comment: There is no such thing as a "special character" - all characters are significant in different contexts. **What _precisely_ is it that you are trying to achieve and _why_?**

Comment: First name contain 2 special character . Index is 3 and 6 . I can get only 3 not 6 .

Comment: Are you dealing with first names or with usernames? Why do you care what characters exist and where?

Comment: am dealing with first name . I need to remove the special character in the firstname . '!' this is a special character that exist 2 times

Comment: ReReplace() is a better function to use.

Comment: Why do you think you need to remove `!` characters? Why would you remove that and not remove `¡` or `‼` characters?

Comment: Again, you're attempting to remove `^` but not removing `˄` or `۸` or `∆` or `▲` which again requires the answer: what is the real underlying issue here? **What is the rationale for characters being removed?** This is a classic example of the [X-Y Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)...

Comment: I found the answer : we have to mention /^ and // instead of ^ and /

Comment: I think your approach is wrong.  Instead of trying to come up with every possible invalid character, why not declare the valid ones and deal with anything that is not one of those.  Also, stripping invalid characters is a bad idea.  I suggest telling the user what was wrong and making him fix it.

Comment: Dan, that's still the wrong approach. Is `é` an invalid character? For people who have it in their name it's potentially as insulting to tell someone their name is invalid as it would be to silently remove it.

Comment: **In almost all situations, removing/restricting characters is unnecessary.** In a few situations, such as when forced to deal with old hardware with fixed character sets (e.g. embossed card printers), it might be necessary to _translate_ unprintable characters, e.g. from `œ` to `oe`, from `ß` to `ss` and so on, but there's been no indication that is the case here.